# EventEmitter Subscribing not working as expected, how to update value in component using subscribe

Tags: angular

I like to subscribe to `EventEmitter` in a `component`. I wrote this code in Service

```
import { Injectable, OnChanges, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { area } from "../model-classes/area"
import { city } from "../model-classes/city"


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class servicetalk implements OnChanges
{
    ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
       
    }
  area: string;
  areachange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }
  setArea(lang) {
    this.area = lang;
    this.areachange.emit(this.area);
  }

  getArea() {
    return this.area;
  }

  MainToCity(i: string): void {
    this.area = i;
    this.areachange.emit(this.area);

  }

}
```

And in my Component I am using this component code that also includes subscribing to EventEmitter

```
  import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { servicetalk } from "../../services/lh-component-talking"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-city',
  templateUrl: './city.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city.component.css']
})
export class CityComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
    alert(this.areaTxt)
    }
  areaTxt: string;
  constructor(ser: servicetalk) {
    ser.areachange.subscribe((area1) => { this.areaTxt = ser.area });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
 
    
  }

}
```

I am using this line get get the value in city component

```
  ser.areachange.subscribe((area1) => { this.areaTxt = ser.getArea() });
```

That `subscribe` is `undefined`

Basically I have one set of component,template. Clicking this template item my city template shows with cities

Master template is "area" clicking on any area cities get displayed. So on clicking on area I call getArea to set the area.

This is my area `component`

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { LhClientServiceService } from "../../services/lh-client-service.service"
import { area } from "../../model-classes/area"
import { servicetalk } from "../../services/lh-component-talking"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-area',
  templateUrl: './area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./area.component.css']
})
export class AreaComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  areas: area[];
  selectedArea: string;
  constructor(private ser: LhClientServiceService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, public talk: servicetalk)
  {
  
  }




  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAreas();
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
    this.cdr.detectChanges()
  }
  getAreas(): void {
    this.ser.getArea();;
    this.cdr.detectChanges()


    console.log(this.areas);
  }
  onSelectArea(sa: string): void {
    this.selectedArea = sa;
    this.talk.setArea(sa);
   

  }

}
```

But now the problem is when I click on area, it's not updating variable in city component. So my question now is how can I handle eventEmitter changes and display update when click on area (txtArea in city component should get update and display the respective data in city template). How can I refresh city component based on value change in EventEmitter?

Comment: What is `componenttalk` ? Need more code

Comment: @SachinGupta its typo its servicetalk

Comment: please update the code in question. If its a typo in code, it might give you some compilation errors.

Comment: same error regardsless

Comment: `Servicetalk` and `servicetalk` are 2 different variables.. Please check the console/terminal for any compilation errors.

Comment: its `servicetalk` compiler gives nothing on this.

Comment: @Alex the code you posted would not compile. Post the actual code that compiles. And format it properly so that it's readable.

Comment: You can even use RxJs Subject if you are having problems with Event Emitter then

Answer (score 0):

made this example and it would work for you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhazlx

change

```
ser.areachange.subscribe((area1) => { this.areaTxt = ser.area });
```

}

for this

```
ser.areachange.subscribe((area1) => { this.areaTxt = area1});
```

and create a event call

`setArea`